# PHP - Error in variable definition

Tags: php, cakephp

I cant figure out what is wrong with the following code:

```
class ArticlesController extends AppController{
    var $name = 'Articles';
    // Variable $today is defined here so it can be used
    // in other functions in this same class 
    var $today = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime('now'));
    var $helpers = array('Video');

    function frontpageArticles(){
        $articles = $this->Article->find(
            'all',
            array(
                'conditions' => array(
                    'Article.published' => 1,
                    'Article.publish_date <=' => $today // USED HERE
                )
            )
       )
    );
    return $articles;
    }

    // ...
}
```

I am getting the following error message:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting ',' or ';' in /home/XXXXXXXX/public_html/app/controllers/articles_controller.php on line 10
```

And this is in LINE 10 `var $today = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime('now'));`

Thanks,

Comment: @des I see two opening parenthesis, and two closing - no mismatch there.

Comment: Right.... Julien said I cannot use date() function there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To elaborate further on what Julien's answer stated, you can't use functions in variable assignments in a *class declaration*, you can of course when you're defining normal variables.

A way around this would be to assign your values in the constructor, like so:

```
class ArticlesController extends AppController
{
    public $name = 'Articles';
    // Variable $today is defined here so it can be used
    // in other functions in this same class 
    public $today;
    public $helpers = array('Video');

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->today = date('Y-m-d H:i:s'); // You also don't need strtotime('now');
    }

    public function frontpageArticles()
    {
        $articles = $this->Article->find(
            'all',
            'conditions' => array(
                'Article.published' => 1,
                'Article.publish_date <=' => $this->today // USED HERE
            )
        );
        return $articles;
    }

    // ...
}
```

Just a side note, `var` is PHP4 syntax, so if you're using PHP5 I would highly suggest that you use the access modifiers ie. `public`/`private`/`protected` to define both your fields and methods based on how they will be used.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed code. Another great PHP lesson for me.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use functions eg. date() in class variable declarations.

Comment: Yes, `'Article.publish_date <=' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime('now'));` if you're not using that date elsewhere, otherwise define it in your constructor.

Comment: I am using it in a few more functions.... I might have to try the constructor then.. thanks

Answer (score 1):

you cannot call function in class property definition, define your var like:

```
var $today;
```

and then set it in your function:

```
$today = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime('now'));
```

if you'd like to set it once- create a `__construct` function

```
function __construct(){
    $today = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime('now'));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use SQL? I use CakePHP 2 and this is how I do it, works fine.
Also I think you are missing an array:

```
$this->Article->find('all', array(
     'conditions'=>array(
           'Article.published_date<=NOW()'
     )
));
```

Comment: you have to write it in the key, if you use it like this, not as a value. Just like i did!